# BAZEL it's possible to download different external dependencies depending on the target I build?

Tags: android, sdk, bazel, bazel-rules

I have project in which I want do build android and non-android targets. My `WORSPACE.bazel` file has defined android related dependencies.

```
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 33,

)
http_archive(
    name = "rules_android_ndk",
    ....
)
load("@rules_android_ndk//:rules.bzl", "android_ndk_repository")
android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
    api_level = 33,
)
register_toolchains("@androidndk//:all")
```

The problem is that code above requires to have Android's SDK/NDK downloaded to my computer no matter which target I want to build.

I don't want to other developers (who works on that project, but not on Android's target) have to download Android SDK.

Is there any preferable approach to skip using some dependencies, depending on a building target ?
I know that I cannot create conditions in `WORKSPACE` file but maybe it's achievable in other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Bazel only looks at what's needed to build what's requested, so usually if nothing Android-related is requested the `android_sdk_repository` and `android_ndk_repository` repo rules shouldn't be loaded. However, with the transition to toolchains, using `register_toolchains()` will cause that repo to be loaded. So `register_toolchains("@androidndk//:all")` will cause the ndk to be loaded, and the Starlark version of `android_sdk_repository` similarly: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/blob/6cd2cbb345eff9c94462498501d83cf700357113/examples/basicapp/WORKSPACE#L39-L42

The workaround in place for `android_sdk_repository` (both Starlark and native) is to generate an empty toolchain that will produce an error if it ends up being actually used (e.g. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/blob/6cd2cbb345eff9c94462498501d83cf700357113/rules/android_sdk_repository/empty.template.bzl#L56-L66)

However `android_ndk_repository` (the starlark version as used in the question) doesn't yet produce an empty toolchain if `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` is not set. But there's an in-progress change to add that: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android_ndk/pull/63

A temporary workaround is to remove the `register_toolchains()` and instead register the toolchains with `--extra_toolchains` on the command line (and this can also be placed into the `.bazelrc` as something like `build:android --extra_toolchains=@androidndk//:all` and then `--config=android` on the command line). The drawback is that you have to remember to set this whenever you build an Android target.

Comment: Alternatively, some toolchain repositories add a layer of indirection, where the repository with the toolchain rule depends on another repository for all the actual toolchain files. This way only the first (small) repository has to be created for everybody, and the second (large) one is only downloaded when it's used. [toolchains_llvm[(https://github.com/bazel-contrib/toolchains_llvm) does this, for example.

Comment: @ahumesky this empty.template looks promising. Now I'm using `android_sdk_repository` from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android in version `0.1.1`. I tried to use repo `rules_android` from the commit you posted above, but it looks like this is not stable version, so I will try to fork version `0.1.1` and add there something similar to that `empty.template`. Thanks!

Comment: The 0.1.1 version of rules_android is really just a wrapper around the "native" android rules built into bazel (they're being converted to starlark). The native version of android_sdk_repository should also support an "empty" toolchain: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/a2351994aed848f5c5da938a10f3a8a29f0b5556/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/android/AndroidSdkRepositoryFunction.java#L226-L231

Comment: Although I don't think the native version of android_ndk_repository has an "empty" toolchain

Comment: @ahumesky hmm.. version `0.1.1` returns error if sdk is not available, so I'm not convinced about that support, unless I'm missing some additional setup. 
But switched implementation of `android_sdk_repository` (this from release version `0.1.1.` to actual one from main brach of https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/tree/6cd2cbb345eff9c94462498501d83cf700357113) and it works for me right now.